# Card Program in Java

Tags: java

For this project I'm attempting I need to check if a hand of 5 cards, given as an array of 5 integers, is a straight. Right now I'm not sure how to check this as the array is not ordered and we are not allowed to use the `Arrays.sort()` method to sort it. The only way I can think of right now is to manually sort them using loops but I think this would be inefficient. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code. Don't be concerned about the efficiency of sorting five things unless this is explicitly stated for the project.

Comment: It sounds like your teacher wants you to sort them using loops.

Comment: I think the inefficiencies can be dealt with at a later stage (probably not a stage at all for this _project_). Just start coding and see where it leads you.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be sorted? How about iterating all your cards, storing the lowest and highest one, and checking whether they are 5 apart? (max - min + 1).

I wouldn't bother about efficiency at this stage. Not to mention for an array of 5 integers.